# current_user can see comments only to his posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

What I have:

```
scaffold Post title body user_id
scaffold Comment body tag post:references
post has_many :comments
```

Current comments controller:

```
  def index
    @comments = Comment.where(tag: [1, 3])
  end
```

I want to enable current devise user to see a list of comments to all only his posts. How can it be done? Something with `current_user`?

Comment: please explain on what  you  need

Comment: I want to enable current devise user to see a list of comments to all only his posts. something like `comment.user_id = current_user_id`

Comment: You want to display in view comments by only current_user with respect to posts by current_user....Right?

Comment: list of comments to all only his posts? what does " to all" mean here?

Comment: To all only his posts. You are both right

Comment: you may wana look at https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can setup a `has_many :through` relationship directly on the `User` model assuming you already have a `has_many :posts` relationship defined and the appropriate relationship on `Post` and `Comment`. For example,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments, through: :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Now, since `devise` gives you `current_user`, getting a user's comments is straightforward

```
def index
  @comments = current_user.comments
end

def show
  @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
end
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: This is the simplest answer that actually worked for me. Thank you Bart, thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to base a query off of information in the column of an associated model, you should use either a `.joins` or a `.include` call. Based on the setup you have indicated, this ought to be what you need:

```
@comments = Comment.joins(:post).where("posts.user_id": current_user.id)
```

Or simply:

```
@comments = Comment.joins(:post).where("posts.user_id": current_user)
```

It may be worth breaking this off into a scope on the Comment model if you intend to call it elsewhere.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  scope :on_user_posts, ->(user) { joins(:post).where("posts.user_id": user) }
```

then you can call this in the controller:

```
@comments = Comment.on_user_posts(current_user)
```

You can also chain this scope with the conditions you already have, if needed:

```
@comments = Comment.on_user_posts(current_user).where(tag: [1, 3])
```

Comment: 1. When I do .joins it says `Association named 'posts' was not found on Comment`, though with a query I can see `comment.post.user_id`.
2. When I ddo scope it says: `undefined method 'scope' for User::CommentsController:Class`

Comment: On your Post model, you'll need to add `has_many :comments` and on your Comment model, you'll need to add `belongs_to :post`. My apologies, I had assumed these were already present.The scope must be defined on the model, not the controller. You use the named scope in the controller, but define it in the model.

Comment: The associations are already present, I even doublechecked. That is what makes it weird. `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError in User::Comments#index`,`Association named 'posts' was not found on Comment`.

Comment: you need to use `joins(:post)` instead `joins(:posts)`

Comment: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: comments.user: SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" INNER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."id" = "comments"."post_id" WHERE "comments"."user" = 3`

Comment: Ah, I was posting to hastily ;) and I forgot to specify the table to query in the where clause. I have updated the answer to use `where("posts.user_id": current_user)`. Sorry for the confusion. And yes, MayankJ is correct about `joins(:post)`.

Answer (score 2):

Define associations and scope in the model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    scope :on_user_posts, lamda{ |user| joins(:post).where("posts.user_id = ?", user.id) }
```

And you post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
```

Now call this scope

```
@comments = Comment.on_user_posts(current_user).where(tag: [1, 3])
```

Comment: `undefined method `lamda' for #<Class:0x51a06c8>`

Comment: use this code
`scope :on_user_posts, ->(user) { joins(:post).where("posts.user_id = ?", user.id) }`